# How to enter a tab character in gedit if replacement with spaces is set up?

Tags: gedit

Some programs require tab characters to work, e.g. `make` requires tabs in `Makefile`s. If `gedit` is configured to replace tabs with spaces, it's painful to change the settings every time or copy a character from another document.

I'm using 3.10.4 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Install a plugin for gedit

1. Clone the repository `git://git.gitano.org.uk/personal/liw/makefiletab3.git`

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/src
   cd src
   git clone git://git.gitano.org.uk/personal/liw/makefiletab3.git
   ```
2. Create the plugin folder for gedit

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins
   ```
3. Create a symbolic link

   ```
   ln -s ~/src/makefiletab3 ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/makefiletab3
   ```
4. Change the Python version in `makefiletab3.plugin`

   Open the file

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/makefiletab3/makefiletab3.plugin
   ```

   and replace

   ```
   Loader=python
   ```

   with

   ```
   Loader=python3
   ```
5. Restart gedit and activate the plugin

   [image]

Comment: The git repo link is stale. I get an error when I tried to clone it.

Comment: I used this https://github.com/polazarus/gedit-makefiletab.git, but gedit isn't detecting the plugin.

Comment: This worked, https://github.com/krichter722/makefiletab3

Answer (score 15):

You can insert a literal <kbd>Tab</kbd> character in gedit by using the GNOME Unicode input mode:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

and then enter <kbd>9</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The horizontal tab character is Unicode code point `U+0009`. This will insert a tab regardless of your preferences to expand tabs or not.

Comment: The most suitable answer for me.

Also, if gedit has automatic indentation enabled this should be done once per block, as subsequent lines will inherit TAB as indentation symbol(s).

Answer (score 6):

You can create shortcuts to quickly change this setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor insert-spaces false
```

Comment: Good idea. I Would remove the hint that it's possible to use another program because people might see a reason to not upvote because the title indicates that the question is about `gedit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to **insert a number of tabs** into a script or document **without changing** the tab **configuration** in gedit:

- Wherever a tab is required **enter a unique string of characters (e.g. `tab!`)** to be used as a **replace token** when needed.
- When you need the actual tabs, use **Find and Replace** (CTRL+H) to **find the `tab!` and replace with `\t`**

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to use a tab character instead of space characters, click on "Tab Width" in Gedit's bottom bar, and uncheck "Use Spaces" check box.

When you are done inserting your tab character(s), simply click on "Tab Width" again, and reset the number of spaces (2, 4, or 8) that represent a tab. Obviously, this only works if you are using one of the default values of 2, 4, or 8 spaces.
[image]